# Android Studio: Preview is missing in View -> Tool Windows ->

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, preview

In Android studio the window of "Preview" is missing.
Also it is missing in View -> Tool Windows ->

[image]

I have tried to click on: Window -> Restore Default Layout
But That didn't help...

**How can I restore Preview window?**
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's not on the edge anymore. Open an XML and look on the bottom. They put both views as tabs

[image: See here]

Comment: Thanks, I know the design mode, but I want the Text mode with Preview window on the right...

Comment: Weird... I can see the option on the menu when I have the XML as context. Try that

Answer (score -1):

Click on the Preview button on the Right

[image: here]